# Wordpress: SQL forget username and password

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

[Update] So I was just a wordpress user about few months back. I skipped paying for hosting and instead created backup of everything including mySql database.

Now, I seem to have forgotten to keep a note of my sql username and password.

Now, I have two questions

**First: Is username in my wp.config same as that of my sql username and password?**

**Seccond: It is throwing an error "Error Establishing network connection"**

For the process I followed was, Installed mamp, went to phphMyAdmin, imported my SQL database successfully, changed the username from mysite.com to http://localhost (Database name is same as that of what it appeared in wp-config.php

and moved all the files in HTDOCS directory (primary root directory).

How can I fix it?

Here is wpconfig file

``````
<?php

/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'z0t4o3o2_Spaceyfi');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

define('WP_MEMORY_LIMiT','128M');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.`````
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the Codex.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
``````

And this is what I am doing in my sql database (or the only change I have done after importing my database -> Changed SiteURL and HomeURL)

[image]

Comment: The details in your wp-config are definitely the details for your database, so that's the first. I'm not sure how to help you with the second as I don't use MAMP, hopefully, another user can shed some light.

Comment: For the second question; the standard username for MAMP is `root` and the standard password is `root` try these settings. And change `http://localhost` to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`

Comment: @JariRengeling tried that (changing username and password to root) but it still says error establishing network connection

Comment: @RahulPatel can you send your connection to your mysql?

Comment: @JariRengeling I am kind of noob here, not sure about what you mean by sending connection to your SQL (How can we do that?). If I go to localhost:8888, I see two folders there, one is standard wordpress and second one is uberhunt folder (containing all my files), Wordpress one works but clicking on uberhunt folder throws an error. Also, Updated my question

Comment: What happens if you change the `siteurl` and `home` options to `http://localhost/`?

Comment: @DaanWilmer doesn't work

Comment: 1. Are you sure mamp is running?
2. On what port is apache running?